# How to edit each list when I used ListView.builder to automatic created many Listile?

Tags: android, flutter

First I used the StreamBuilder to call the data from Firestore and return to the ListView.Builder.

And it works.Then it created more than ten ListTile ,but I wanna use the ExpansionTile to each List and give them different style.

So is it possible to edit every List?
How can I do? That was confusing me.

Can anyone give me some points and ideas or keywords? Q_Q

Thanks!!

And here is my code.

```
  body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('TWrate').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
              _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
        );
      }),

 _buildListItem(){
   reture Container(
      child:Card(
         child:ListTile(
            ...
         )
        )
       )
     }
```

Comment: means you want to style 10 items differently? or if there are 100 in the lists then 100 items differently?

Comment: I solve the problem thanks for your amswer